# Scala: How to pattern match a class type that extends a parent class?

Tags: scala, class, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use pattern matching to match classes that extend from a parent class, but also restrict the classes you can pass as a parameter using `classType: Class[_ <: Animal]`. Here's an example:

```
  class Animal
  class Dog extends Animal
  class Cat extends Animal

  def returnAnimalSubtypeObject(classType: Class[_ <: Animal]): Animal = {
    classType match {
      case _: Dog => new Dog()
      case _: Cat => new Cat()
    }
  }

  returnNewClass(Class[Dog])
```

But this returns the following error message:

```
<console>:16: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Dog
 required: Class[_$1] where type _$1 <: Animal
             case _: Dog => new Dog()
```

I think I'm not understanding something fundamental here since I'm still a beginner. Could someone explain what's the best approach to solving this?

Comment: What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve? You shouldn't be using `Class` as a beginner.

Comment: This looks like a bad example of a factory function. Probably not the best thing you could do in Scala, but have a look [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-factory-pattern-in-scala/).

Comment: Is your problem just **match a subtype from parent class** ?  Is the function just a example or has some meaning ? Is `returnNewClass`  a typo ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Class` object for `Dog` is not a `Dog`: it's a `Class`.

With the proviso that there's almost certainly a better way to accomplish what you actually want to do, you could:

```scala
def returnAnimalSubtypeObject(clazz: Class[_ <: Animal]): Animal =
  if (clazz == classOf[Dog]) new Dog()
  else if (clazz == classOf[Cat]) new Cat()
  else new Animal()
```

Answer (score 1):

At the high level, doing what you are trying to do does not seem very useful even if it did work: `returnNewClass(Class[Dog])` does not seem to have any advantages over just `new Dog`.

With that caveat, a proper way to define that function would be something like this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def animal[T <: Animal : ClassTag]() = implictly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.newInstance
```

Two interesting things here:

`[T <: Animal : ClassTag]` defines a type parameter `T` that must be a subclass of `Animal` and have a `ClassTag` avaialable for it at call site.
This definition is equivalent to `def animal[T <: Animal](implicit ct: ClassTag[T])`.

`ClassTag` is a scala object that provides a link between a scala type and the corresponding java class that implements it. So, once the `ClassTag` is avaialable, you can get a handle to `.runtimeClass` from it, and then instantiate it using java reflection api.

The way to call that function would be `val d = animal[Dog]`, though, I'll say again that I just don't see how this adds any value over just `new Dog()` ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to implement something like ADT(Abstract Data Type). I would prefer to use `sealed trait` or `sealed abstract class` since it's better in pattern matching.

see also: https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/definitions/adt.html

For purpose of understanding, I change some code here.

```scala
  sealed trait Animal
  case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
  case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

  object Animal {
    def description(animal: Animal): String = animal match {
      case Dog(name) => s"this is a dog named $name, it can bark"
      case Cat(name) => s"this is a cat named $name, it can not bark like a dog"
    }
  }


scala> Animal.description(Dog("dog"))
val res0: String = this is a dog named dog, it can bark
                                                                                
scala> Animal.description(Cat("cat"))
val res1: String = this is a cat named cat, it can not bark like a dog
```

When we use `sealed` keywork, the Scala compiler will check the pattern match is exhaustive or not.

```
// if we miss a type to match
def returnAnimalSubtypeObject(x: Animal): Animal = x match {
      case d: Dog => d
    }

// it will show warning.
 match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Cat(_, _)
[warn]     def returnAnimalSubtypeObject(x: Animal): Animal = x match {
[warn]                                                        ^
[warn] one warning found
```

Comment: What's the point of returning the parameter the function was passed, just with possibly worse types for the calling code?

Comment: The previous example is not good, I have updated it.